# dilemma with hana-bi and hana hi

Tags: word-choice, meaning

So I know that **hana-bi** (**はなび**) means *firework*s but if I want to say in more artistic way (and not about fireworks) *flower of fire/flames* can I say **hana hi** (**はなひ**)? Whether it will be understood? And can i still write it as **花火** or something different. Or maybe it will always be a mistake. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want to refer to fireworks, 火花 means spark(s). And sparks look like pretty flowers sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have another idea, maybe flower of fire could be written as 花の火, because の indicate possession or maybe some other particle could work?

Comment: Perhaps 火の花 would be better for "flower of fire" (garden of house = 家の庭). Even so, I don't know if 火の花 would work. Will leave it to a native speaker. An expression involving resemblance may work... [火らしい花](http://tinyurl.com/zlhbzeq), [火見たいな花](http://maggiesensei.com/2015/11/11/how-to-use-%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84-mitai/), [火っぽい花](http://maggiesensei.com/2009/09/16/%E3%80%8C%E3%80%9C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%81%84%E3%80%8Dish-like-video-follow-up/) or something.

Comment: 火らしい花 is illogical. It means "flowers that are identified as fire".

Comment: would like to correct myself - my 見たい should have been written in kana. :)
@user4092 thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: "flower of fire/ *flames* " >> 「火」もいいけど・・代わりに「[炎]{ほのお}」も使ってみたら・・・？

Comment: Could you provide some context? Where are you going to use the phrase? Maybe for the title of an art work, or in song lyrics, or in a poem...?

Comment: name of artistic group, fire dancers to be more specific

Answer (score 7):

火の花 (building on OP's suggestion of 花の火) might be a good answer.

For what it's worth, Mario's fireball is described as [**火の玉**](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AA_%28%E3%82%B2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%A9%E3%82%AF%E3%82%BF%E3%83%BC%29#.E4.B8.BB.E3.81.AA.E3.82.A2.E3.82.AF.E3.82.B7.E3.83.A7.E3.83.B3) (= ball of fire) - not "fire that looks like a ball" or "spherical fire" but literally "ball of fire":

> 片手から**火の玉**を生み出し前方に向けて撃つ技。

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing really wrong about 火の花, but without some kind of context it seems a bit odd. You can always add other words to clarify that you are speaking in simile / metaphor:

夢の中で花を見た。その花が不思議なほどに鮮やかな紅蓮色をしてて、**まるで**火そのものでできている**かのように見えた**。

Answer (score 3):

I think 火の花 is ambiguous.It is difficult to be able to be judged fire or flowers by the word without context.

If you want to say about flowers, you say 火のように美しい花(beautiful flowers like fire) and if you want to say about fire, you say 花のように美しい火(beautiful fire like flowers).

If you use のような,　のように, it will be clear.

Comment: as I wrote earlier what if it's for the name of artistic group not for something like a poem or something that has a context honestly. Is it nearly impossible to do this in short amount of signs? Like abstract thing: "flower of flames", which is not a flower and not completely flame. This just came to my mind and I'm really curious , my Japanese is really, really basic.

Comment: Is this Japanese group? Or do you want to translate "flower of flames" in Japanese? If you don't need to get clear on the meaning, I think 炎花、花炎、火の花, 花の火, etc are no problem. 火花 and 花火 seem to be a matter because they have already the meaning.

Comment: Just wanted to translate it. Thank you very much!